# two character commands not stored in bash history in mac terminal

Tags: bash

I enter commands with just two characters something like 'ae' or 'tt' but they are not stored in history and I can't up arrow to them. How do I fix this in Mac terminal using bash as shell?

Comment: Works for me on macOS 11.2.3 and bash 3.2.57(1). What is your `sw_vers && bash --version`?

Comment: @SalilSurendran : What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `echo $HISTIGNORE` and `echo $HISTCONTROL` say in your shell?

Comment: > echo $HISTIGNORE
?:??
> echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoredups
> echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release

Answer (score 0):

HISTIGNORE ?:?? was the problem. It basically says ignore one character and two character commands. Removing that from .bashrc fixed the issue.